# Looking for feedback on Data Model

Tags: sql, relational-database, data-modeling, datamodel, conceptual-model

I'm taking a Coursera course called Advanced Data Modeling and practiced creating a conceptual model as well as a logical ER diagram. The prompt gave me the following fields and said to create a data model using them:

- **Order ID**
- **Client name**
- **Client address**
- **Order Date**
- **Delivery Status**
- **Delivery Date**
- **Contact**
- **Number Email**
- **Item name**
- **Item price**
- **Total cost**

Below is the difference between my answer and Coursera's. I'm not as concerned about the attributes that Coursera added and I didn't. My main questions are:

1. For the conceptual model, Coursera says "place" in place of my "client info" but the contact info is just as important. How would one determine the best relationship between two tables?
2. For the Logical ER Diagram, why would you separate **Delivery Status**
   and **Delivery Date** if it's tied directly to the order?
3. For the Logical ER Diagram, I created an **Order Detail** table because
   my thinking was you want to separate out each order by all the items
   within the order. It seems like Coursera's answer doesn't take into
   account that a customer might order multiple items in the same
   order. My understanding is that this is going against 2NF and
   causing redundant data if a customer orders more than one item. Can
   someone confirm if I'm missing something here?

My Answer
[image: My Answer]

Coursera's Answer
[image: Coursera's Answer]

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. PS [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. PS This site has both black & white background modes, so don't use images with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

1. A contact can change their contact info but you would still save the historic contact info, so `1 contact to n contact-info`
2. An order can have multiple deliveries since the "deliver" can return for some postal error. Nobody at home? Another delivery, another delivery status and delivery date. You could also have another table to this, `1 order n deliveries`.
3. I would use the same principle of 1 and 2 so for me, your answer is more valid.